# How to use texi2dvi to run latex generating PDF?

Tags: xetex, pdf, texi2dvi

I use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex` to generate PDFs, but now I want to use `texi2dvi` to generate them, however every time it shows errors as follows:

```
texi2dvi(file="Letter__Oct11.tex",pdf=TRUE) failed
```

```
LaTeX errors:
! Fatal fontspec error: "not-pdftex"
! 
! 
! Requires XeTeX or LuaTeX to function!
! Requires XeTeX or LuaTeX to function!
! 
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! For immediate help type H <return>
! For immediate help type H <return>
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| This is a fatal error: LaTeX will abort
|...............................................
```

Answer (score 2):

`texi2dvi` looks at the value of the `LATEX` environment variable; from a bash shell the command

```
LATEX=xelatex texi2dvi file.tex
```

uses `xelatex` to typeset `file.tex`.

Comment: where is LATEX? how to replace? thanks! I don't understand how to use xelatex typeset file.tex

Comment: @eva You should be more precise in your question about how you're calling `texi2dvi`.

Comment: I just use texi2dvi(file="example.tex",pdf=TRUE)

Comment: @eva Where do you write that command?

Comment: texi2dvi looks at the value of the LATEX environment variable; from a bash shell the command I don't understand how should I change the codes inside the texi2dvi

Comment: The syntax `texi2dvi(file="example.tex",pdf=TRUE)` is not a shell command.